# SharePoint List Modal Empty

Tags: 2010

After configuring the v5 Masterpage for SharePoint 2010, I have noticed that the modal for view/edit forms is not loading the fields, only the ribbon.

Watching the console in IE Developer Tools, I am not noticing any errors, so I'm assuming I may have missed something within the masterpage itself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no v5.master in 2010. You may have accidentally removed important parts of the master page, or broken them. Things happen. Typos happen. "v5" is an example for that. Restore the original v4.master into your custom master page and start over. Test often.

Comment: my mistake, I was referring to Kyle Schaeffer's v5 master page. What I found was I needed to change my styles a bit, in my case this worked. .ms-dialog .s4-pr { width:100%;}